# Material-UI Error: Object is not a function within makeStyles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The error:

```sh
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
  13 | import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  14 | 
  15 | 
> 16 | const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  17 |     ...theme
  18 | }));
  19 |
```

Code:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    ...theme
}));
```

**Why do I get the above error?**
Everything was working but suddenly i got that error, may be after i updated npm `npm -g update` but i am not sure.

Can someone help out?

Edit: this is how i am using useStyles:

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

then i am using the classes to style my elements like this:

```
<Button className={classes.button} />
```

`classes.button` get the button rule from the global theme and use it to style the button

Comment: Are you able to add more snippets for us to see what's happening in the code? Especially how `useStyles` is being utilized...

Comment: @MwamiTovi i updated it

Comment: Ok, that's fine. And where are you using the `classes` variable after declaring it? e.g. `classes.input`; Are you able to include that too?

Comment: @MwamiTovi updated :)

Comment: Am trying to follow what you want to achieve, does this means that somewhere you have this `const theme = createMuiTheme({...})`. Where you defined a theme, right?

Comment: yes, in ```App.js``` file

Comment: @MwamiTovi i am sorry for your time, but i found the problem, it was wrong import stament

Comment: I was about to ask you this,
`import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';` (Re-export with a default theme) vs `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';` (Original module with no default theme). Was that the issue? Because one of those comes with your theme while the other doesn't...

Comment: yes, i imported it wrongly like this
```import { makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles```

Comment: @MwamiTovi you can add your answer, just for your time, and i will accept it, thanks for help

Comment: You probably wrongly import makeStyles, because your syntax is correct. Also, you should not spread the theme (`...theme`) inside of makeStyles object. Its contents are not valid JSS values. Here is what the theme is: https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To remove the need to systematically supply a theme,
> the default `Material-UI` theme is applied to the re-exported `makeStyles` modules.

```js
// Re-export with a default theme
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// Original module with no default theme
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

**But also be careful of "mistaken" imports.**

```js
// for example, this is wrong
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles';
```

Like what [@Code Eagle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63239277/material-ui-error-object-is-not-a-function-within-makestyles/63239746#63239746), here, had fallen into. It can be a pain to debug such errors:)
Here's a good read about this from the [Material-UI basics](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/).

Comment: I think this type of nasty errors is really hard to debug, but when i find this error the next time i would go to see if i am imported right :)

Comment: The challenge like you had here is that, if it was working the first time, then the last place you suspect is a wrong import statement.:-(

Answer (score 1):

When I updated my imports to use the re-exported ref to `makeStyles` in the `core` module, I mistakenly failed to delete `makeStyles` at the end of the import statement when I made the change.

Thank you for the post, I wanted to make the solution a little more explicit for those that update their imports to core.

Bad

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles';
```

Good

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/';
```